# RESB: Declaring and Filling Uninitialized Data

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm

I have this code:

```
    extern  printf      ; the C function, to be called

SECTION .bss
    array resb 10

SECTION .data       ; Data section, initialized variables

    data times 10 db 0
    a:   dd 5       ; int a=5;
    fmt: db "a=%d, eax=%d", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0'


SECTION .text                   ; Code section.

global main     ; the standard gcc entry point

    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0

print:
    push    ebp     ; set up stack frame
    mov     ebp,esp
    inc ebx
    mov     eax, [array + ebx]  ; put a from store into register
    ;add     eax, 1
    push    eax     ; value of a+2 FIRST
    push    dword [a]   ; value of variable a SECOND
    push    dword fmt   ; address of ctrl string
    call    printf      ; Call C function
    add     esp, 12     ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

    mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
    pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op

    mov     eax,0       ;  normal, no error, return value

    ret         ; return

main:               ; the program label for the entry point

    call print
    ret
```

I need to create an `array` for 10 bytes. Then I want to fill this memory, I try to do somethink like this:

```
int array[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    array[i] = i;
```

Do I understand correctly that `resb` is a static bytes (variables)? This data exists throughout the entire life cycle of the program.

Comment: Yes, stuff in `.bss` and `.data` is static. Note that `resb` is bytes not integers (dwords). If you want `int array[10]` you should use `resd`.

Comment: It does not matter in this case. I just do not realize, how can I fill this memory. I talk about ```array``` in ```.bss``` section.

Comment: Your question was whether it's static, not how you fill it. You fill it the same as in your C code. Use a loop and set each item. Or do not use `.bss` and put your initialized array into `.data` directly.

Comment: Okay, how can I change value in ```data``` or ```array```? I can move this in some register and I can do somethink like this ```mov eax, x```, then ```add eax, 1```, but I will have the defference values. ```eax``` will be equal two, for instance, but ```x``` will be qual one.

Comment: You write it as normal, e.g. `mov [array+ecx*4], ecx` assuming `ecx` is your loop counter.

Comment: Note that `int` is 4 bytes, so if you want space for 10 `int` (dword) elements, you need to reserve 40 bytes.  e.g. with `resd 10`.